# Vim swap file sweep and recovery

Tags: bash

This is the draft contents of a function intended to be run after a system crash in order to quickly review all of the recent vim swap files. They will be loaded up into and displayed in a vim instance, and then presumably if desired they will be saved using vim commands into actual files. Following this, rm will be run to offer user to delete the swap files. In theory, unless user gets distracted by something in between quitting the vim instance and responding to the rm -i prompt, there shouldn't be cases in which the swap file gets preserved, but better to be safe with these things I guess, and add additional 2 keystrokes to the workflow per file.

```
vim=gvim
n=5
d=.
days_back=3
echo Searching 
find "$1" -type f \( -name '.*.s??' -o -name '.s??' \) -exec ls -lta {} + | head -n "$2"
find "$d" -type f \( -name '.*.s??' -o -name '.s??' \) -mtime "$days_back" -printf "%AY%Am%Ad%AH%AM%AS %p\0\n" |
    sort -n     |
    head "$n"   |
    sed -e 's/\d+ //' | sed -e 's/\n//g' | while read -r -d '' f; do
        $vim -r "$f" && rm -iv "$f" || 
                echo ERROR: vim recovery command returned failure status.

    done
```

2nd iteration:

```bsh
function swap_sweep () {
    # Usage: swap_sweep [ DAYS_BACK ]
    #   Sweeps the current working directory for swap files, sorted by the most recent order,
    #   going DAYS_BACK days back if it is provided, or 3 days back if it is not.

    # [[ -d $1 ]]   && ( d="$1" && n="$2" ) || n="$1"
    # [[ -z $d ]] && d=.

    vim=gvim
    wd=.
    [[ -n $1 ]] && days_back=$1 || days_back=3
    # I wonder if these awk commands will accomodate filenames that contain whitespace...
    # I'm guessing not, and wonder how that could be done?
    find "$wd"  -type f \
                -mtime "$days_back" \
                    \( -name '.*.s??' -o -name '.s??' \) \
                -exec ls -ltago {} +             \
        | awk '{ print $4, $5, $6, $7, }'        \
                                 \ 
        | tee | awk '{ print $4 }' \
        | while read -r f; do
            $vim -r "$f" && rm -iv "$f" ||
                    echo ERROR: vim recovery command returned failure status.
        done
}

alias sws=swap_sweep
```

3rd iteration:

````bsh
function swap_sweep () {
    days_back=3
    vim=gvim
    n=5
    wd=.
    echo Searching 
    find "$wd" -type f \( -name '.*.s??' -o -name '.s??' \) -mtime "$days_back" -exec ls -ltago {} + |
        awk '{ print $4, $5, $6, $7 }'
    find "$wd" -type f \( -name '.*.s??' -o -name '.s??' \) -mtime "$days_back" -print0 | while read -r -d '' f; do
            $vim -r "$f" && rm -iv "$f" || 
                            echo ERROR: vim recovery command returned failure status.
    done
##  # Usage: swap_sweep [ DAYS_BACK ]
##  #   Sweeps the current working directory for swap files, sorted by the most recent order,
##  #   going DAYS_BACK days back if it is provided, or 3 days back if it is not.
##  
##  # [[ -d $1 ]]   && ( d="$1" && n="$2" ) || n="$1"
##  # [[ -z $d ]] && d=.
##  
##  vim=gvim
##  wd=.
##  [[ -n $1 ]] && days_back=$1 || days_back=3
##  # I wonder if these awk commands will accomodate filenames that contain whitespace...
##  # I'm guessing not, and wonder how that could be done?
##  find "$wd"   -type f \
##              -mtime "$days_back" \
##                  \( -name '.*.s??' -o -name '.s??' \) \
##              -exec ls -ltago {} +             \
##      | awk '{ print $4, $5, $6, $7 }'         \
##                               \
##      | tee | awk '{ print $4 }' \
##      | while read -r f; do
##          $vim -r "$f" &&
##              echo -n "$(ls -lhgo "$f" | awk '{ print $7, "\t", $4, $5, $6 }')    ==> " &&
##              rm -iv "$f" ||
##          echo ERROR: vim recovery command returned failure status.
##      done
}

```
````